# Como resolver problema de carregamento css e js laravel em produção?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Quando executo minha aplicação local, os estilos e o js são carregados normalmente.
Os css e js estão em public/css e public/js.

Em produção não são carregados, abaixo o .htaccess de produção:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ambiente

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Código do app.blade.php

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: A sua configuração de produção não está correta, você usa hospedagem compartilhada?

Comment: Sim, uso mas eu outra aplicação também em laravel que funciona bem. Eu copiei o .htaccess da aplicação que funciona e nada

Comment: Esse é o grande problema Hospedagem Compartilhada, as configurações nunca dão certo, porque, a configuração do Laravel é meio particular mesmo que tenha dado certo em alguma outra é um erro fazer essas configurações. Complicado.

Comment: Virgilio, tem alguma sugestão de hospedagem onde eu pudesse hospedar meus projetos Laravel?

Comment: https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: Mas tem como criar subdominios ou domínios no heroku?

Comment: http://hoo.st/pt-br

Comment: tem sim @MarceloGomes

Comment: Virgilio,estou hospedando no hoo.st/pt-br. este é o problema.

Comment: Eita me indicaram esse agora pouco no site laravel-br.slack.com

Comment: @MarceloGommes me indicaram esse https://forge.laravel.com/ ele pode ser conciliado com Digital Ocean

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=619e33cb5d72&utm_campaign=Referral_Invite&utm_medium=Referral_Program&utm_source=CopyPaste

Comment: Marcelo tente o seguinte no html que importa esses recursos, presumo que seja blade: `<link href="{{url('/css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">` e `<script src="{{url('/js/app.js')}}"></script>`

Comment: Criei uma variável de ambiente .env para controlar as pastas 'public' ou 'não' e  funcionou com '{{{ url() }}'. Valeu

Comment: @MarceloGomes desculpe intrometer na conversa... rs mas o problema está aqui **RewriteBase /ambiente** seu sistema está nesta pasta? Se conseguir colocar todo o seu sistema nesta pasta "*/ambiente"* e configurar o seu apache o nigx com o domínio do seu sistema para apontar para "*/ambiente/public*", creio que terá resolvido seu problema ai, não?

Comment: @MarceloGomes só como opção, caso queira optar por uma VPS, gosto muito da AWS da Amazon e da **OVH**, esta última poder ser um começo, bom e barato. Se precisar de menor latêcia, terá de procurar algo no Brasil mesmo. http://ovh.ca

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim, lembrando que vc terá que salvar o arquivo com essa extensão .blade.php

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```